# Bug w html/css/divs centering text w/ flexbox despite using similar model throughout the site

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have been been centering my code using flexbox in CSS no problem throughout this site I am working on for practice/fun but I have run into what appears to be an inconsistency I havnt been able to debug.

I two div boxes within two larger parent divs. The div boxes sit side by side and within I have circle divs I am trying to place gliphicons and text directly in the middle while ensuring the circle divs radius integrity is not compromised. Please let me know if you have any insights. (gliphicon seems out of place thematically but I'm just trying to debug)

Below I have HTML and CSS snippets:

```css
    .item1 {
      height: 600px;
      width: 49.5%;
      margin: 1px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-weight: 600;
      background-color: #E2E2E2;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
      .circle {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      /*background: #ef8913;*/
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="example-content">
        <div class="parent0">
          <div class="item1">
            <div class="circle">
              <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Ride Your Bike Bareass <br> Through The Desert!</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item0">
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you write the actual problem also in the thread rather than just what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly..

The width / height and padding was your enemy.. Here's what I have done:

```css
    .item1 {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background-color: #E2E2E2;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        /*background: #ef8913;*/
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="example-content">
    <div class="parent0">
        <div class="item1">
            <div class="circle">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Ride Your Bike Bareass <br> Through The Desert!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may need to tweak the .circle width % to make it accurate but these would be the lines to go down.

Comment: required some tweaking but worked very well thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

remove `padding-top` from `.circle` and give padding to all sides

```css
 .item1 {
      height: 600px;
      width: 49.5%;
      margin: 1px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-weight: 600;
      background-color: #E2E2E2;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
      .circle {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
   padding: 2em 1em;
      border: 1px solid black;
      /*background: #ef8913;*/
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="example-content">
        <div class="parent0">
          <div class="item1">
            <div class="circle">
              <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Ride Your Bike Bareass <br> Through The Desert!</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```